# Vectorize to Apply Function to 3d Array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, pytorch

I am trying to apply a function to 3d torch tensor while the function is applied to 2d tensor which is read through the axis 1 of the 3d torch tensor.

For example, I have a torch tensor of the shape `(51, 128, 20100)` (a variable with name `autoencode_logprob`) and the function(rawid2sentence) runs on the input of the shape `(51, 20100)`.

Right now I wrote the code to run with naive for loop, looping one by one with range(128).

However, it’s too slow. Following is the code part that matters.

autoencode_logprobs is the 3d tensor and I need to apply `rawids2sentence` function along its second axis. Any help to vectorize it?

```
for i in range(128):
    output_sent = self.dictionary.rawids2sentence(
        autoencode_logprobs[:, i].max(1)[
            1].data.cpu().numpy(),
        oov_dicts[i],
    )
    output_sent_encoding = ifst_model.encode([output_sent])
```

Comment: With only 128 iterations I'd focus the speed of the task itself, not on eliminating the iterations.

Comment: There are millions of batches to process the same task. Eliminating iteration is the basic and fundamental in deep learning.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know what `rawids2sentence` or `encode` function does, I can help you with to do the max operation.

In the following statement,

```
autoencode_logprobs[:, i].max(1)[1]
```

You identify the index of the maximum values along `dim=1` for each `51 x 20100` tensor. So, the output is a vector of size `51`.

You can perform the same operation in your full tensor of shape `51 x 128 x 20100` and get the output as `128 x 51` tensor.

```
autoencode_logprobs.transpose(0, 1).max(2)[1] # 128 x 51
```

So, if your `rawids2sentence` or `encode` methods can tackle batch inputs, the above change should work for you without any loop.